# Should network firewall rules be secret?

Tags: firewalls

At my workplace only the security team have access to see the rules on the server network firewalls.

Developers and system engineers don't have any visibility, so they just deploy applications to servers and find out what's broken rather than checking application requirements against the rules in advance.

Is this kind of secrecy a normal/valid security practice?

Comment: When developing applications it is very important that developers know the restrictions for the application. Even if the firewall rules should be secret, not sharing information about this may lower productivity of developers, which is key to a successful business.

Comment: It will be better if rules are kept a secret to the outside world and known to the inside, especially to the developers.

Comment: Normal practice is for developers and engineers to understand their application's network requirements, and to work with security or networking to enable the necessary connectivity in advance.  Doing a blind deploy to figure out what's broke suggests a level of sloppy that usually leads to Security hostility.

Comment: For what reason would the developers need access? Why can they simply not request if there is a rule present to allow something? And if there isn't they can request it's added.

Comment: The problem we have is that the security team has never documented or explained to anyone else what the default rules are or how developers and engineers should interact with them in defining requirements.  So some cases work with no need to request anything from security and some don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal that the only people with access to view and review the network rules are the network engineers and the security team.

The development team should know what ports and protocols are required to use their applications and work with the networks team to ensure the appropriate rules are in place. If there are standard ports in use by other applications, these might be re-used. Otherwise, when making changes for testing or deploying to prod, the applications team (or product owner etc) should coordinate with the networks team. The security team should be reviewing the change request to ensure no vulnerabilities are introduced.

Comment: The answers have clearly established it is a normal industry practice, which is what I was wanting to know, so thanks for that.  What I don't understand is that since the rules are the result of accumulated input from engineers and developers, what security goal is achieved by preventing those people seeing them?

Comment: It's part of Role Based Access Control and Principle of Least Privilege for users in general. They should have access to the tools and information required to perform their jobs. Any potentially sensitive security configurations or operations are only relevant to restricted, privileged individuals. While it may be appropriate to share a subset of relevant rules with the developers, knowledge of the full ruleset is in no way required for their purpose and will disclose configurations they could leverage with malice.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. The rules have to be documented, but no other teams should know them.

Developers and system engineers may request for rules to be added (or removed if no longer needed) and that's more than enough.

This is a very good security practice and should remain so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal, because:

1. the set of rules changes in time, including some ad-hoc ones - it would be very hard to translate them to human-readable form just for documentation,
2. the ruleset might be simply huge and also unreadable as a simple technical dump,
3. some of the rules might be "smart", i.e. it might be really hard to give exact condition when they fire - I'm referring here to some Deep Packet Inspection/IDS rules, IP firewall rules are usually deterministic.
4. there might be open holes in single firewalling device, blocked at some next layer. Exposing the ruleset makes it much easier to exploit.
5. the developers need to request inserting not the **rule**, but the **effect**: *I need A running with B, make me a path*, not *insert a rule between 234 and 235 to pass though TCP src port 5548 to 9842*. This is another reason they shouldn't know the ruleset itself, as they would be deceived to repeat [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In this question you're asking if it is OK that someone has taken a photo of keys to your home (even without sharply visible pins). This isn't **immediate** threat, but might expose some sensitive informations - for example the producer and version of a lock, which might be vulnerable to some attack.

Comment: Taking a photo of keys isn't even nearly the same: keys are simple to reproduce from a picture. Actually, that would be more like taking a screenshot of your private SSH keys...

Comment: Locks opened by keys, that are easy reproducible from a picture, are easy opened without any keys. I was talking about "patented" locks.

Comment: Well, keys pretty much rely on the biting being secret, anyone who can copy the key, can get in. Firewall rules don't have anything like that: knowing the rules doesn't let one automatically bypass them. At most, it might help in finding an exploit, as you said.

Comment: Good keys are multi-sided and the pits are not so easy to measure on a photo. Good locks require high key precision. With simple, 1D keys, yes - uncovering any single pit easies opening the lock with a pin.

Comment: Your post is implying you would have to either: print the rules off, put them in a word document, copy them to a text-file that is not the case at all. Most firewalls support read-only access not to mention they're not really that difficult to read at all, in fact, they're pretty self-explanatory and given the fact he is talking about giving the development teams access I am sure they're more than capable of reading firewall rules without needing them put into a "human-readable" format.

Comment: Most firewalls **do not** support read-only access. Application developers usually **are not** capable of understanding firewalling rules. Moreover, giving **any** access to firewalling device to random people is simply speaking - security threat. These devices are also exploitable, these devices happen to have priviledge escalation bugs.

Comment: The trouble with the key analogy is that the developers are supposed to be telling security the pattern for cutting the key.  In which case, what is the problem with them seeing the key once it's been cut?

Comment: No, the developers don't tell the **pattern** - actually your comment was so relevant, that I've added 5th reason in my answer.

Comment: @TomaszPala I am not sure what firewalls you have used however, you're wrong. Most firewalls do support read-only access, any firewall that costs more than $500 will support some form of read-only access. And yes it is a threat, which is why you just don't give them access to the rules at all in the first place :) Also your comment on developers not being able to read these rules is a little ridiculous, as an example https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/91970-PIXASAopenblockports21.gif are you telling me a developer -

Comment: Wouldn't understand those rules? And yes they can get a lot more complex, those are merely an example - I am sure if you put that image in-front of a non-technical person they could figure out what was going on, there is a massive tick for crying out loud. Not to mention they wouldn't be "Random people" would they? Because the devs are not just "Random people"

Comment: Take any Linux box - no r/o firewalling. Not to mention required shell acceess, or some even more insecure GUI. If you're giving such fw example at all ...you must have never seen real-world ruleset. And you're right - there are devs that are not "random people"; many of them are much worse... they do think they understand firewalling, while in fact they have no idea how complex this becomes very fast. If you're a developer, just work within your area of expertise.